# Difference between access to mapped objects in array through for cycle/for in cycle

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I've been working with D3.js library and encountered this for me unknown behavior. I created array containing 100 numbers from 0 to 99 using range function and afterwards mapped function to each member of array like this:

```
var data = d3.range(100).map(function() {
    return {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
})
```

In Mozilla docs about javascript is this map function behavior description:

> Creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

My anticipation was that after execution of this code, my variable data will be an array containing 100 objects, each having attributes x and y set to 0.

I tried to access these objects using two different methods. At first, I tried to use for/in cycle like this:

```
for(d in data){
  console.log(d);
  console.log(d.x + " " + d.y);
}
```

Output of this cycle was:

```
0
undefined undefined
1
undefined undefined
...
99
undefined undefined
```

Then I tried to access each object by index using for cycle like this

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    console.log(data[i]);
    console.log(data[i].x + " " + data[i].y);
}
```

and suddenly, output was quite different, finding and matching all objects with their properties:

```
[object Object]
0 0
[object Object]
0 0
...
[object Object]
0 0
```

I don't understand why accessing objects in array through for/in cycle was not working, but straight index access was successful. I think I might be missing something about how map function maps function results to original array, or maybe for/in cycle access to the array is different than through index. Does anyone know why this happens? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for..in` iterates over array *indexes*, not values:

```
> a = [100,200,300]
[100, 200, 300]
> for(d in a) console.log(d)
0
1
2
```

so, in your first loop you'll need:

```
for(d in data)
    console.log(data[d].x + " " + data[d].y);
```

Comment: The standard disclaimer applies here: avoid `for..in` on arrays, because it will iterate over any enumerable properties (like polyfills and other stuff added to Array.prototype). Usually a `hasOwnProperty` check within the loop is recommended.

Answer (score -1):

as you said,

```
var data = d3.range(100).map(function() {
    return {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
})
```

Creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

for in can be used on objects not array.

for arrays you need to use for loop.

you can follow this

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in
```